# How to archive mail by year in mutt?

Tags: mutt

I have an IMAP folder with 64k emails in it. I would like to archive these by year. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest is to use the tag-pattern feature (bound to <kbd>T</kbd> here) to tag one year of messages, then use tag-prefix save-message (<kbd>;</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> here) to put them in a folder.

Mutt has several pattern matches for date (all which unfortunately take dates in dd/mm/yyyy format). The [mutt manual’s “Pattern Modifier” subsection](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns-modifier) lists them all, but useful are probably `~d` (sent date, the Date: header, specified by the sender, so spoofable) and `~r` (received date). An example for messages received in 2018: `~r01/01/2018-31/12/2018`

If you do yearly archives generally, then you may want lines like:

```
save-hook ~r01/01/2019-31/12/2019 =Archives/2019
save-hook ~r01/01/2020-31/12/2020 =Archives/2020
⋮
```

in your config (unfortunately, I haven't found a way to avoid having to add a few more lines every few years).

An alternative is if you have access to the IMAP server outside of Mutt. For example, I have shell access on my IMAP server running Dovecot (since I run it myself) and thus can use `doeveadm` in a yearly cron job:

```bsh
this_year=$(date +%Y)
last_year=$((this_year-1))
#⋮
newbox="Sent/$last_year"
doveadm mailbox create "$newbox" || true
doveadm -v move "$newbox" mailbox 'Sent' SENTBEFORE "$this_year-01-01" SENTSINCE "$last_year-01-01"
```

Comment: For new mail, I believe you can simply use `set mbox = "+Archive/\`date +%Y\`"` and `save-hook . "+Archive/%[%Y]"`, avoiding having to add lines annually (see [this mutt-users](https://marc.info/?l=mutt-users&m=129340783200660&w=2) thread).

Comment: Such a great answer, did not know dovecot can do that. Thunderbird just broke archiving my emails of the last year, grinding the machine to a halt after working 15 min on 3000 emails. Doveadm did it in under a second.